# Is it safe to remove the 'apt' job from cron.daily?

Tags: apt, cron

I'm running a production server (Ubuntu 14.04 - yes I know it's old!) and a couple weeks ago it started randomly crashing due to lack of memory each night around the time the daily cron job starts.  At first I thought it was a database backup job that I had created (the only cron job on the box that I've made).  After much digging and many angry customers, I found that the job that was causing the crash was "apt". (/etc/cron.daily/apt)

I don't want this to run.  I don't want to risk my server failing, and I can see that when I run it it uses a ton of memory and CPU.

I can see that it's related to the OS package manager and the code appears to be calling apt-config a few times and possibly attempting unattended upgrade (this is NOT something I want to happen on a production server).

Is it ok to remove this job from the daily cron folder?  Are there any consequences I should be aware of if I stop running this file?

Comment: Only supported releases of Ubuntu (*standard support*) are on-topic for this site.  Ubuntu 14.04 LTS is in extended support and now Ubuntu 14.04 ESM thus only supported by Canonical via Ubuntu Advantage and off-topic here.  Refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/05/02/ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr-reached-end-of-life-on-april-25-2019-esm-available/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general it's not best to remove a file belonging to a package that's installed.

In this case, it appears that:

- The file is replaced by apt-compat many years ago, so the apt file may be left over from a much older install
- The file, at least its newer apt-compat incarnation, doesn't do anything if you have systemd because apt instead uses systemd to do the same thing

---

Edit: I did not realise you were running 14.04, goodness.  Drop other priorities and focus on migrating to a supported platform.